# When learning JS, what was your your Aha-moment?

Tags: javascript, learning

**Do you remember when you were learning JavaScript? What was the moment that you suddenly "got it"?** (For example, my CSS aha-moment was when I learnt about the box model...)

The reason I´m asking is that I´m learning JS for 6 weeks, but I still find it quite confusing. Here´s a quote from something I read recently on SO:

> "..functions act similar to values, as
>   method is a property of the object
>   that has a value of a function (which
>   is also an object)."

I´m curious if you were confused as well in the beginning and what was it that made you understand it.

(I´m reading the Sitepoints "Simply JavaScript", the book "Eloquent JavaScript" and following Lynda´s Essential JavaScript tutorial. I don´t have any programming expeirence and was terrible at math ;)

Thanks!

Comment: I find the quote confusing and unclear to be honest, and I've been using JavaScript in anger for a number of years, so I'm not surprised if it's confusing for someone new to the language :)

Comment: Quote and confusion is coming because that quote is trying to say that functions are first class objects in javascript. Keep pounding, and you will provide yourself with the source of 'a-ha' moments: Additional frames of reference.

Answer (score 15):

I think the biggest "AHA" moment for me was when I fully grasped the following:

**Variable values can be anything, including functions**

```
var person = {
    name: 'Sean',
    getName: function() { return this.name; },
    numbers: [7, 11, 41]
}

var myvar = person.name;
alert(myvar); //prints name
alert(myvar()); //"myvar" is not a function error
alert(myvar.length); //undefined

myvar = person.getName;
alert(myvar); //prints the contents of the function as a string
alert(myvar()); //calls the function
alert(myvar.length); //undefined

myvar = person.numbers;
alert(myvar); //prints contents of array
alert(myvar()); //"myvar" is not a function error
alert(myvar.length); //prints 3
```

Answer (score 10):

To me it was when I understood that the context (what `this` points to) of a function can be changed arbitrarily

http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/

Answer (score 10):

I agree with what some of the other answers have touched on; **The A-ha moment for me was when I *understood* what a closure was**.

I posted an answer to the question [What is a closure?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40454/what-is-a-closure/40708#40708) to help explain this.

Without understanding closures, Javascript is a pretty limited language, with a few nice shorthand syntax features like `[]` for arrays and [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) (`{}` for objects), and in the context of the browser, the DOM (`window`/`document`).

However once you understand closures, **a lot of understanding falls into place**:

- What a **prototype** really is ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841175/trying-to-understand-the-point-of-prototypes-in-javascript/4841209#4841209))
- Why prototypes are the **key to OOP in Javascript** ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186244/what-does-it-mean-that-javascript-is-a-prototype-based-language/186279#186279))
- How most **event handlers** in Javascript *really* work (it can seem like magic without understanding closures)
- How to save yourself a lot of code (and/or time) with **callbacks**

#### Resources

- I haven't been through this whole site but it looks like a great resource, touching on these topics: http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html
- Check out http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/ for a great tutorial on Javascript

Answer (score 4):

I think the most essential language 'Aha's for me in Javascript were

- Functions as objects
- Closures
- Prototype-based object-orientation
- Scoping in JavaScript

For all these topics, you should find plenty of resources on the web.

(And don't think everything will become totally logical: JavaScript *is* confusing)

Answer (score 3):

javascript was hard for me when I first started learning it some years ago because I first started learning web development from the server-side end of things (php and perl).

It wasn't so much the syntax or OOP or anything that eluded me, moreso the live and event-driven-ness of javascript - going from "do this and this and this and serve it up and you are done" to "do this and this and this and then we're in a constant state of waiting for something to happen and respond until the user leaves the page".  That really threw me for a loop.

I don't think I can name anything in particular that really made it sink in (no definitive "aha!" moment - if I had to name a specific moment, I'd say when I was learning AJAX for a search suggestion script, but IMO that's just arbitrary) but when I did eventually grasp the difference, everything got a lot easier from there :)

Answer (score 1):

When I finally grasped the idea that I can redefine any part of the language to whatever the crap I want it to. In this respect, its even more powerful than C. For example, if I don't like the standard `toString()` function, then I'll implement my own:

```
x.toString = function () {
    return "this is MY toString function biatch!";
}
```

Comment: How is this really different from overriding?

Answer (score 1):

When I realized that you could set a property on a function object.

Also when I finally understood what the prototype was.

```
function Alpha(){
    return 'aplha';
}
Alpha.Beta = function(){
    return 'beta';
}
Alpha.prototype.Delta = function(){
    return 'delta';
}

Alpha(); // 'alpha'
Alpha.Beta(); // 'beta'
new Alpha().Delta(); // 'delta'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Obj() {
    this.x = 42;
    this.value = function() {
        return this.x;
    };
}

var o = new Obj();
o.value();        // 42
var f = o.value;
f();              // undefined??
```

And the *a-ha* moment when you finally catch on these results.

Answer (score 0):

Aha moment #1, for me: Realizing that JavaScript, the language, is distinct from its primary use: dynamic HTML and client-side web programming. I would be frustrated with JavaScript, when I really I was frustrated with the DOM and browser incompatibilities.

Aha moment #2: Understanding that inheritance can be executed in many ways. Typical class-based inheritance is just one. There are others, namely prototype-based (the style used in JavaScript).

With respect to #1, I can't resist recommending [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596517742). It treats JavaScript as a fine language in its own right.

Answer (score 0):

No block scoping and hoisting.

```
foo(); // function executes, no error

if (...) {
  function foo(){
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just Scheme with syntax.

That was the big one for me.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery was basically the 'a-ha' moment for me. The syntax felt familiar after having a lot of experience with LINQ/lambda syntax in C#.